# How to parse embed sql in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4, dsl

Consider following example input:

```
namespace Client
{
    sql FindByQuery
    {
        SELECT * FROM client_Profile
        WHERE 1 = 1 

        #ifNotEmpty(City,    sql{ AND `City`    = @City })
        #ifNotEmpty(Zipcode, sql{ AND `Zipcode` = @Zipcode })

        #ifNotEqual(State,   "NY", sql{ AND `State` = @State })
        #ifEqual(IsReactive, 1   , sql{ AND `WONum` LIKE CONCAT('B%', @WONum) })

        #include(CommonOrderBy)
    }
}
```

There is two separate language in code:

1. Any raw text, include whitespace, only if not starts with '#' and ending with '}' (The SQL statement)
2. My control blocks(namespace/sql) and macros('#....').

How to parse the inner SQL statement as raw text and handle the macros starts with '#' correctly?

Or is there any example?

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: By using the ANTLR4 lexer mode, I successfully parsed it.

Comment: Good, so maybe add the answer then and accept it so the everyone knows that this questions is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR4 lexer mode can do that, it means create a separate lexer g4 file, define two mode: DEFAULT mode and the SQL mode.

The "sql FindByQuery" statement push to SQL mode, and the "}" pop back to DEFAULT mode.

In these two separate ANTLR4 modes, lexer can be totally different.